# how to position background images side by side with height auto, also in responsive

Tags: css

I am working for a web page, where I need to place four background images in col-7 and two in col-5. My problem is, it is also a responsive website for all screen size. So, I have to set width and height for all media queries and also place new images for all sizes. It will be almost 4*15=60 images. I want place only single image, only 15 images without bothering height size.
Here is my sample code

```
<div  class='col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12' style='padding-right:0;padding-left:0;'>

<div id="rotator-wrapper">
```

```
  <div id="img1" class="rotator-image"></div>
  <div id="img2" class="rotator-image"></div>
  <div id="img3" class="rotator-image"></div>

</li>
   <li>
  <div id="img4" class="rotator-image"></div>
  <div id="img5" class="rotator-image"></div>
  <div id="img6" class="rotator-image"></div>

</li>

  <li>
  <div id="img7" class="rotator-image"></div>
  <div id="img8" class="rotator-image"></div>
  <div id="img9" class="rotator-image"></div>

</li>

<li>
 <div id="img10" class="rotator-image"></div>
  <div id="img11" class="rotator-image"></div>
  <div id="img12" class="rotator-image"></div>


</li>
```

```
      </div>




    <!---->

<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">


    <div id="boos_style" >

<a href="boost_skill.php"><div id="boost_img"></div></a>

<a href="boost_skill.php"><div id="jobs_img"></div></a>
</div>
```

```
</div><!--header_post end-->
```

Comment: Can you create working fiddle? Or an image of what you are trying to accomplish as I am not fully understanding your needs. Cheers

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake here all id such as img1,img2.....img12 will be the class. My problem is, if I want to set a background image I need to set height fixed. For this reason, I need to do a lot of media queries and also set image for every screen size. I want to simplify that

Comment: instead of   <div id="img1" class="rotator-image"></div> my code is
 <div class="rotator-image img1"></div>

Comment: now what is the solution

Comment: Please refer back to working fiddle. Do you know how to create one?

Comment: No, I do not know how to create this.....

Comment: You can use https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: there is no solution